# Как правильно составить регулярное выражение в котором только строчные символы и одна и только одна заглавная

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой кейс нужно составить регулярное выражение  которое позволяет выделить все строки отвечающие условиям:

1. Должна состоят только из букв
2. Одна и только одна из букв является заглавной

Если составить что то вроде `/^[a-z]+[A-Z]{1, 1}$/`,  то получим строку из строчных букв в конце которой одна заглавная, это не то что нужно.  Есть какие-нибудь мысли? Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Является ли заглавная буква обязательной в слове?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То есть, исходя из условий, нужно получить слово, которое является единственным в строке и содержит одну заглавную букву.

```
/^[а-я]*[А-Я][а-я]*$/gm
```

```js
let sTxt = `Есть такой Кейс нужно
Составить регулярное
Выражение
коТорое
поЗвОляет
выделитЬ`;
let rExp = /^[а-я]*[А-Я][а-я]*$/gm;
let aRes = sTxt.match(rExp);

console.log(aRes);
```

Comment: Да это работает, нужно было правильно использовать *

Comment: В современных средах выполнения JS лучше использовать [`^\p{Ll}*\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*$`](https://regexr.com/65d4n) (обязательно с флагом `u`, флаги `g` и `m` по ситуации) - такое выражение матчит символы любого алфавита поддерживаемого Юникодом.

Comment: @yar85: согласен, но тут недавно вопрос пробегал, типа "как заставить отказаться от IE" :)

Comment: @UModeL, ну... я не вижу какого-то конфликта между использованием новых фич и отказом от IE: такой вопрос скорее говорит за потребность в новом вместо старого, что только подкрепляет рекомендацию :) Babel, кстати, содержит плагин для юникодовских регулярок в env-пресете, так что их использование вполне безопасно при сборке в ES5 (то есть, в таком случае работать будет и в IE, если все еще хочется его поддерживать).

Answer (score 0):

```js
let sTxt = `Есть такой Кейс нужно
Составить регулярное
Выражение
коТорое
поЗвОляет
выделитЬ`;
let rExp = /^[а-я]*[А-Я][а-я]*$/gm;
let aRes = sTxt.match(rExp);

console.log(aRes);
```

```js
let sTxt = `Есть такой Кейс нужно
Составить регулярное
Выражение
коТорое
поЗвОляет
выделитЬ`;
let rExp = /^[а-я]*[А-Я][а-я]*$/gm;
let aRes = sTxt.match(rExp);

console.log(aRes);
```

Comment: И чем данный ответ отличается по сути от более раннего варианта?